# How to convert PHP Foreach statement to forloop

Tags: php

```
$cast_name_list = explode(',',$result[$x]["cast_name"]);
$cast_profile_path = explode(',',$result[$x]["cast_profile_path"]);
$cast_character = explode(',',$result[$x]["cast_character"]);

foreach( $cast_name_list as $index => $cast_name ) 
{
echo 'name = '.$cast_name.' ';
echo ' profile path = '.$cast_profile_path[$index].' ';
echo ' character name = '.$cast_character[$index].' ';
}
```

I want to convert it into forloop for some reasons, but i don't know how. Can someone help me please?

Comment: You are looking for the array_keys function: Get the array_keys, use a for loop on that to retrieve the given key which then retrieves your $index to be used in the current functions (your current style is a bit nicer I would say)

Answer (score 0):

PHP for loops execute a block of code a specified number of times.

```
for (init counter; test counter; increment counter) {
    code to be executed
}
```

Parameters:

- init counter: Initialize the loop counter value
- test counter: Evaluated for each loop iteration. If it evaluates to TRUE, the loop continues. If it evaluates to FALSE, the loop ends.
- increment counter: Increases the loop counter value

The foreach loop works only on arrays, and is used to loop through each key/value pair in an array.

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    code to be executed;
}
```

For every loop iteration, the value of the current array element is assigned to $value and the array pointer is moved by one, until it reaches the last array element.

You can see more information here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp